# Alternatives to a UNION query in Access 2010 Web Database

Tags: ms-access-2010, parent-child, union

I need to assign one of multiple parent types to a single child item. The problem I encounter is that in an Access 2010 web database I cannot create a Union query to bring all the potential parents (from multiple tables) into a single drop down / listbox.

I'm a bit green to all this and could be going about it completely wrong. I'm very open to suggestions. Here is my example:

- Contracts are the parent of Subcontracts.
- Both Contracts and Subcontracts have a Statement of Work (SoW).

  - Contracts and Subcontracts can both be direct parents of a SoW.
- Each SoW will have only one parent

  - SoWs are split into paragraphs (not overly consequential)

With a union query I would build the database this way:

- Contracts table
- Subcontracts table
- Union table for contracts and subcontracts
- Lookup to union table from SoW table in order to select either a contract or a subcontract as parent from a single data source.

The problem here is that I cannot create a union query in a web database.

My only other thought is to construct the database in this fashion:

- Contracts table
- Subcontracts table
- Contracts SoW table
- Subcontracts SoW table

This design (using two tables) might work more effectively for data entry as there could be issues with subforms when attempting to use a union table. I'm not sure as I haven't yet tried. With this method, the Access report should be able to bind the subcontract to the parent contract and display all data in a detail section. However, this design still means that I will use two separate tables to house identical data.

Answer (score 0):

I would put the two contract tables together into one table that would look something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE ContractTable(
  ContactID INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, -- Possibly an autonumber
  [various contract columns],
  ParentContract INTEGER
);
```

Note, I know this is not Access friendly syntax. I usually use bigger DBs, but you should be able to get the idea.

Then your query to find parent contracts is `SELECT ... FROM ContractTable WHERE ParentContract IS NULL`.

To find sub contracts `SELECT ... FROM ContractTable WHERE ParentContract IS NOT NULL`.

My concern with this approach is that if you need to search through chains of contracts (i.e. A parent of B parent of C parent of D, and you need to go from A to D), you could run into recursive SQL which I don't think Access can handle. You'd have to do it VBA code.

Comment: Yarr and Web Databases can't do VBA code... lol. Quite the rabbit hole. I *believe* that there will only be "A parent of B". Does the "ParentContract" field then reference the ContractID values from the table it is in?